# Postgres: JSONB string to timestamp with TZ

Tags: json, postgresql

In postgres database (9.4) i have data saved as JSON object. Including some datetime elements. In order to do time comparision in sql query I have to convert this string to timestamp. I have tried this query:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2015-05-22T10:56:04.949Z','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS');
-- dummy query just to test converting

OUTPUT: 2015-05-22 10:56:04.949+03
```

It works basically fine, except, I cant figure out how to include timezone parameter there. This string is in UTC time 10:56AM, if I run this query, I'll get 10:56 in +03 timezone (+03 is my local timezone). According to Postgres documentation, TZ should be added to format string to get timezone as well, but it does not work.

How to format this string so that it includes also timezone from initial date-time string ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to parse timezone from string.
However if you know your timestamp is always in UTC timezone you can use:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2015-05-22T10:56:04.949Z','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS')::timestamp at time zone '00:00'
```

Comment: I tried this with "2016-08-12T18:33:17.157Z" and I got an exception. ERROR: hour "18" is invalid for the 12-hour clock. SQL state: 22007. Hint: Use the 24-hour clock, or give an hour between 1 and 12.

Comment: Try using `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that from Postgresql 12 characters with no specific meaning are no longer ignored, so the "T" preceding the time causes an error in the previous answers. The pattern needs to skip the T by enclosing it in double quotes

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2015-05-22T10:56:04.949Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.MS')::timestamp at time zone '00:00'
```

From the docs:

> Prior to PostgreSQL 12, it was possible to skip arbitrary text in the input string using non-letter or non-digit characters. For example, to_timestamp('2000y6m1d', 'yyyy-MM-DD') used to work. Now you can only use letter characters for this purpose. For example, to_timestamp('2000y6m1d', 'yyyytMMtDDt') and to_timestamp('2000y6m1d', 'yyyy"y"MM"m"DD"d"') skip y, m, and d.